# Annotating a Django queryset through two relations

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models that represent People and Books, which are joined via a through-model that can indicate their role (e.g. 'Author' or 'Editor'):

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.ChartField()

    people = models.ManyToManyField('Person',
                            through='BookRole', related_name='books')


class BookRole(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='book_roles')

    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', related_name='roles')

    role_name = models.CharField()
```

And I have a Reading model that represents an occasion a Book was read:

```
class Reading(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')

    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

I know how to get a list of `Person`s ordered by the quantity `Book`s associated with them:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from .models import Person

Person.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('books')) \
                .order_by('-num_books')
```

But how can I get a list of `Person`s ordered by the number of times their `Book`s have been read (i.e. the number of `Reading`s related to their `Book`s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the standard django double underscore notation:

```
Person.objects.annotate(num_readings=Count('books__reading')) \
            .order_by('-num_readings')
```

See the docs on [joins and aggregates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) for more info.

Comment: Doh, of course! I'd been way over-thinking this and looking into subqueries and suchlike. Thanks @Alasdair for putting me straight.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I can never remember. Phil will be able to tell us.

Comment: Yeah me neither haha. That's why I always use explicit `related_name`.

Comment: Having tried it, @Alasdair is right... It's `book.reading_set.all()` to get a queryset of the readings, but `Count('books__reading')` works for the annotation.

Comment: @PhilGyford yes, there's no need for subqueries in this case. If you wanted to limit which books you are counting the reads for (e.g. only count reads for books with `genre='mystery'`), then it gets more tricky.